# Home controller method parameter not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, methods, parameters, controller

I modified the about method in the home controller in my MVC web application (named "webapp")  as follows

```
public String About(String x)
{
    return "Hello this is the About action and the parameter you entered is "+x;
}
```

But when I ran the web app in the URL of the web browser as "http://localhost/WebApplication3/Home/About/10"
The output was

> Hello this is the About action and the parameter you entered is

The output was did not display the value of the parameter which is 10 in this situation! How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to run this url: `"http://localhost/WebApplication3/Home/About?x=10"`

Comment: Thanx its working but why didn't my method work?

Comment: Probably you don't have route configured for this.

Comment: how to configure route for this?

Comment: Name your string parameter "id" instead of "x".

Comment: Thanx how can we change this for any parameter

Comment: @Amal "any parameter" - what do you mean?

Comment: works for parameters like string x,string y, etc like ones not only string id

Comment: If you're in MVC 5, you can use `RouteAttribute` to mark each route, e.g. `[Route("something/{x}")]` or `[Route("something/{y}")]`. But if you want to use `RouteConfig` with MVC 4/earlier, define each route with "x" and "y" parameter separately by order.